# Controle de estoque

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal estou a desenvolver um carrinho de compras...

cheguei em uma parte que acabou que deu errado... seguinte o carrinho consiste em receita do produto é adicionais e remoção de ingredientes

```
tabela produtos
id     nome      id_lanche    preço
1     X-egg       1            7.00
2     X-tudo      2            9.00

tabela receita
id     nome      id_lanche    preço     quantidade (quantiodade no caso e quanto o produto tem de cada item)
1     alface      1            1.00      1
2     bacon       1            2.00      2
3     Cheddar     1            2.00      2
4     Bife        1            3.00      1
5     alface      2            1.00      1
6     bacon       2            2.00      2
7     Ovo         2            2.00      1
8     Bife        2            3.00      1

Tabela estoque
id     nome      quantidade
1     alface      10
2     bacon       5
```

acontece que existe 1 alface com id 1 e outro com id 2...
ele nao consegue identificar o item para dar baixa... no estoque
eu pensei pelo nome so que nao axo que e 100% eficaz... se o nome tive escrito errado nao vai funcionar...

vocês poderia me ajuda a desenvolver uma forma eficaz?

Comment: Mais uma melhoria, pela sua modelagem mostrada aqui, não vejo a necessidade do campo `id_lanche` na tabela `produtos`, uma vez que os campos `id e id_lanche` são iguais. Então você poderia relacionar apenas com o `id`, ficando assim: `receita.id_lanche = produtos.id`, a não ser que você tenha uma outra tabela chamada `lanche` que não está sendo mostrada no exemplo, ai pode ignorar tudo que eu disse.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, obrigado pelo concelho. já usei ele no projeto, eu tinha ate outras coisas meio que duplicadas tbm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

você tem que guardar na tabela receita o id do alface, como no estoque o alface é id = 1, então no lugar do nome "alface" na tabela da receita, você guarda o id, suas tabelas ficariam parecidas com isso:

```
tabela produtos
id     nome      id_lanche    preço
1     X-egg       1            7.00
2     X-tudo      2            9.00

tabela receita
id    id_produto  id_lanche    preço     quantidade (quantiodade no caso e quanto o produto tem de cada item)
1     1           1            1.00      1
2     2           1            2.00      2
3     3           1            2.00      2
4     4           1            3.00      1
5     1           2            1.00      1
6     2           2            2.00      2
7     5           2            2.00      1
8     4           2            3.00      1

Tabela estoque
id     nome      quantidade
1     alface      10
2     bacon       5
3     Cheddar     6
4     Bife        8
5     Ovo         12
```

Dessa forma, você consegue atualizar o estoque do item sem conflitos.

Comment: muito obrigado funcionou perfeito! :D